# SQL Server Cumulative Invoice Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem with legal record keeping. I am allowed to offset an invoice if an invoice reversal is entered in the system within 10 days. How can I accomplish this without double counting reversals?

```
IF OBJECT_iD('tempdb..#INV') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #INV 

CREATE TABLE #INV 
(
     LEGAL_REC_ID varchar(8), 
     INVOICE_DATE date, 
     INVOICE_CATEGORY varchar(3), 
     INVOICE_AMOUNT decimal (18,2)
)

INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/01/20','CHG','500')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/02/20','CHG','250')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/05/20','REV','-400')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/15/20','REV','-300')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/20/20','CHG','100')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/21/20','REV','-500')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/22/20','REV','-100')
INSERT INTO #INV(LEGAL_REC_ID, INVOICE_DATE, INVOICE_CATEGORY, INVOICE_AMOUNT) VALUES(  'A','01/23/20','REV','-700')

+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+
| LEGAL_REC_ID | INVOICE_DATE | INVOICE_CATEGORY | INVOICE_AMOUNT |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+
| A            | 2020-01-01   | CHG              |         500.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-02   | CHG              |         250.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-05   | REV              |        -400.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-15   | REV              |        -300.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-20   | CHG              |         100.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-21   | REV              |        -500.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-22   | REV              |        -100.00 |
| A            | 2020-01-23   | REV              |        -700.00 |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
| LEGAL_REC_ID | INVOICE_DATE | INVOICE_CATEGORY | INVOICE_AMOUNT | NET_DUE | CUMULATIVE AMOUNT |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
| A            | 1/1/2020     | CHG              |            500 |     100 |               100 |
| A            | 1/2/2020     | CHG              |            250 |     250 |               350 |
| A            | 1/20/2020    | CHG              |            100 |       0 |               350 |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Show us what code you've tried.

Comment: I don't think you've completely described your scenario in the question e.g. according to the data you've provided, how do you determine which invoice to apply reversals to when there are multiple candidates? What has happened with the reversals of 21st, 22nd and 23rd of January, that exceed the invoiced amount?

Comment: There are multiple invoices per day?  It needs some sort of primary key.

Comment: @shugs . . . I think this is quite a complicated question and I don't fully understand it.  Is only one reversal allowed per CHG?  Why isn't the net amount negative?  What happens to the reversals that are not included?  What if the only available reversal is larger than the charge amount?

Answer (score 1):

The following query gives you what you want, but I must agree with the second comment on your question:

> What has happened with the reversals of 21st, 22nd and 23rd of January, that exceed the invoiced amount?

Letting those records vanish into thin air does not *feel* right, certainly not for financial data... I added a `NET_DUE2` column next to `NET_DUE` to illustrate. Also, the invoice reversal on `2020-01-15` goes completely missing in this overview (there is no `CHG` in the preceeding 10 days in your sample data).

That said: the solution below uses multiple common table expressions (CTE's) to isolate each step of the process. Have a look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fe043e29d3afb89c726560c6c3fe6e9) to see how the solution was built in steps. As a result, there are a lot of groupings and more efficient solution may very well exist.

1. The first CTE (`cte_chg`) selects the charges `CHG` and does an additional grouping on the invoice date in case there would be multiple charges on the same day. Next to that it also adds a new column that contains the previous charge date `PREV_INVOICE_DATE`.
2. The second CTE (`cte_rev`) takes the output of the first CTE and joins it with the reversals `REV`. A `left join` in case no reversals occur within the next 10 days (`ir.INVOICE_DATE <= dateadd(dd, 10, c.INVOICE_DATE)`). Do not include any reversals that are within 10 days of the previous charge (`ir.INVOICE_DATE > coalesce(dateadd(dd, 10, c.PREV_INVOICE_DATE), c.INVOICE_DATE)`). The `coalesce()` in there resolves the fact a charge may not have a previous charge (as is the case for the first row). Adding the sum of the applicable reversals to the charges gives the due amount `NET_DUE`.
3. The final step is a running total over the due amounts and gives `CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT`.

**Solution**

```
with cte_chg as
(
  select i.LEGAL_REC_ID,
         i.INVOICE_DATE,
         lag(i.INVOICE_DATE) over(partition by i.LEGAL_REC_ID order by i.INVOICE_DATE) as PREV_INVOICE_DATE,
         i.INVOICE_CATEGORY,
         sum(i.INVOICE_AMOUNT) as INVOICE_AMOUNT
  from #INV i
  where i.INVOICE_CATEGORY = 'CHG'
  group by i.LEGAL_REC_ID,
           i.INVOICE_DATE,
           i.INVOICE_CATEGORY
),
cte_rev as
(
  select c.LEGAL_REC_ID,
         c.INVOICE_DATE,
         c.INVOICE_CATEGORY,
         c.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
         case
           when c.INVOICE_AMOUNT + coalesce(sum(ir.INVOICE_AMOUNT), 0) > 0
           then c.INVOICE_AMOUNT + coalesce(sum(ir.INVOICE_AMOUNT), 0)
           else 0
         end NET_DUE,
         c.INVOICE_AMOUNT + coalesce(sum(ir.INVOICE_AMOUNT), 0) as NET_DUE2
  from cte_chg c
  left join #INV ir
    on  ir.LEGAL_REC_ID = c.LEGAL_REC_ID
    and ir.INVOICE_DATE <= dateadd(dd, 10, c.INVOICE_DATE)
    and ir.INVOICE_DATE >  coalesce(dateadd(dd, 10, c.PREV_INVOICE_DATE), c.INVOICE_DATE)
    and ir.INVOICE_CATEGORY = 'REV'
  group by c.LEGAL_REC_ID,
           c.INVOICE_DATE,
           c.INVOICE_CATEGORY,
           c.INVOICE_AMOUNT
)
select r.LEGAL_REC_ID,
       r.INVOICE_DATE,
       r.INVOICE_CATEGORY,
       r.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
       r.NET_DUE,
       sum(r.NET_DUE) over(order by r.INVOICE_DATE rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT,
       r.NET_DUE2,
       sum(r.NET_DUE2) over(order by r.INVOICE_DATE rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT2
from cte_rev r
group by r.LEGAL_REC_ID,
         r.INVOICE_DATE,
         r.INVOICE_CATEGORY,
         r.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
         r.NET_DUE,
         r.NET_DUE2;
```

**Result**

```
LEGAL_REC_ID INVOICE_DATE INVOICE_CATEGORY INVOICE_AMOUNT NET_DUE CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT NET_DUE2 CUMULATIVE_AMOUNT2
------------ ------------ ---------------- -------------- ------- ----------------- -------- ------------------
A            2020-01-01   CHG              500.00         100.00  100.00              100.00   100.00
A            2020-01-02   CHG              250.00         250.00  350.00              250.00   350.00
A            2020-01-20   CHG              100.00           0.00  350.00            -1500.00 -1150.00
```

Comment: Very helpful & insightful! The problem we have is sometimes two invoice charges are reversed together. So, if the reversal on 1/5/2020 was more than 500 (e.g., $750), the solution does not capture the carry forward. Thank you very much!